# AWS Lambda Logs/Result Unrelated to Lambda Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Below is a basic Lambda function with a slight modified response body (includes my first name instead of 'Lambda')

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Isaiah!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Despite this, the response obj looks like

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

I will also say that console logging doesn't come up in cloud watch either. Why is this SO?

Comment: You didn't click the "deploy" button in the Lambda interface after you updated the code.

Comment: CloudWatch logs won't show up if you didn't give the Lambda function the appropriate CloudWatch logs IAM permissions.

Comment: Man, that's frustrating. Appreciate it mark, post this as the answer if you want the clout!

Comment: I actually have the right role defined, I just thought the deploy button did more than it actually does haha

Comment: do checkout whether the same aws lambda is opened in some other tab or somewhere..because of conflict it sometime shows this kind of output

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing the Lambda function's code via the online editor you need to click the "deploy" button in the Lambda interface after you are done editing code.

For the missing logs, you need to make sure you give the Lambda function the appropriate IAM permission to create the CloudWatch logs.